# How to call a rest API which returns object of two different types

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am calling an external API (on which I do not have a control to make any change) using Spring's RestTemplate. The API returns response with an array as response body if the results are found and if not it returns response with String as response body stating "No records found". I am getting an exception when I am getting the no company found message because I typecasted the RestTemplate call to the custom object

```
ResponseEntity<Student[]> studentDetails = restTemplate.getForEntity(studentUrl, Student[].class);
```

The above code throws exception when the API returns String message "No records found".
What is the best way to deal with such a scenario?

Comment: You may want to use some wrapper object as the response, which would possess a `Student[]` attribute, maybe also a `String` message attribute. Or you may send a 404 response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case, you probably may use it like that

```
ResponseEntity<Object> studentDetails = restTemplate.getForEntity(studentUrl, Object.class);
```

And then check for the response type and cast the result.